# App Ionic funciona bien en un móvil y mal en otro móvil con misma versión de Android

Tags: ionic, apk

He generado un apk en modo --prod y en mi móvil loguea bien y muestra listado de productos bien desde Firebase. Todo funciona correctamente. Pero ese mismo apk instalado en otro móvil con la misma versión de Android, te saca de la app, o no muestra los productos. ¿Qué puede ser?

Comment: Según el móvil que sea, los privilegios que se le da a la app automáticamente pueden cambiar. Mira a ver que privilegios están activos en uno u otro y comparas. Además, como última opción puedes mirar los logs y detectar así el error que ha producido el cierre inesperado.

Comment: OK! Comprobaré lo de los privilegios. ¿Cómo se miran los logs de un dispositivo android? Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Con CatLog podrías pero tienes que ser ROOT.  [Descárgalo aquí](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en_US)